# Appengine text search not working on numeric operations = and : queries on date field

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using google appengine text search service with sdk 1.7.5,  I've saved a field "created_time" and it is a date field. When I am trying to use numeric operations on created_time field, equal to operation is returning no results (no matches returned).

Even If I query on date fields with >= or <= results returned are processed with > or < conditions

Queries

`created_time = 2013-04-13` or `created_time : 2013-04-13` (neither of them worked),

`created_time >= 2013-03-13 AND created_time <= 2013-04-13` (Returns results between those 2 dates, excludes those dates)